# Mutual authentification with JavaScript Client

Tags: javascript, java, ssl

I had to perfrom a mutual authentification with certificate between a Javascript client and a Server running with TomCat

I change the configuration of my server so it will find the trust/keys store
But for the client part,i found many exemples with a JAVA client using the javax.net.ssl to define parameters (keyStore/Truststore) but i did not found anything for a JavaScript Client

is it Possible and how i can do it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let TLS handle the client and server authentication. That's not something you want to do in Javascript

Comment: Our client app is in JavaScript so i'm forced to use it ... There is a library or something else that can help me to do it Or i have to checked manually the certificat send back by the server?

Comment: Your client app does not run in a web browser but runs as standalone Javascript?

Comment: yes it's exactly that